# Error when trying to access app's Heroku URL in Dart

Tags: heroku, dart

I am trying to deploy the sample app from [this](https://www.dartlang.org/codelabs/deploy/) Dart tutorial to Heroku. I am following the steps exactly and in fact the deployment seems to be successful as `git push heroku master` completes with:

```
http://houseofdart.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:houseofdart.git
```

However when I then try to visit the Heroku URL for the app I get application error saying **"An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."** Now for the logs, I can see there's something alarming in them but I don't know how to fix it. Here are my heroku logs (pasting only a part for brevity):

```
2014-02-05T01:08:59.029794+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./dart-sdk/bin/dart bin/basic_http_server.dart`
2014-02-05T01:08:59.050211+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./dart-sdk/bin/dart bin/basic_http_server.dart`
2014-02-05T01:08:59.845661+00:00 app[web.1]: Unable to open file: /app/bin/basic_http_server.dart
2014-02-05T01:09:00.064575+00:00 app[web.1]: Unable to open file: /app/bin/basic_http_server.dart
2014-02-05T01:09:01.134177+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 255
2014-02-05T01:09:01.761486+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 255
2014-02-05T01:09:01.144540+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-05T01:09:01.145311+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-02-05T01:09:02.927148+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./dart-sdk/bin/dart bin/basic_http_server.dart`
2014-02-05T01:09:03.696680+00:00 app[web.1]: Unable to open file: /app/bin/basic_http_server.dart
2014-02-05T01:09:04.793026+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 255
2014-02-05T01:09:04.808956+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-02-05T01:09:57.277242+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=houseofdart.herokuapp.com request_id=78cc25ea-964a-4bfe-95a4-cf09437a22ad fwd="178.43.176.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Not sure why it would be impossible to open /app/bin/basic_http_server.dart ? 
My code is just downloaded from [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/deploy-codelab/archive/master.zip), as per the Dart tutorial, my Procfile looks exactly like it is supposed to:

```
web: ./dart-sdk/bin/dart bin/basic_http_server.dart
```

I've also tried to follow the steps from Seth Ladd's blog (sorry, StackOverflow won't allow me to paste the third link, but google "Running Dart in the Cloud with Heroku" and you'll get the post I am talking about), but no luck either - even worse so, the push is being rejected and the error message I get is `You need to specify DART_SDK_URL to a Dart SDK for Linux`, hence I guess the tutorial instructions are more up to date.

What could be wrong with this?

Comment: Are you sure all files were added to git? Does `git ls-tree -r master --name-only` show your bin/basic_http_server.dart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I suspected, it wasn't really a Dart nor Heroku's problem. The answer is really simple: I had bin/ folder added to my **~/.gitignore_global** file, when I removed it everything went smoothly.

Thank you MarioP as your suggestion really pointed me in the right direction, of course the command you suggested didn't show any bin/ folder at all.